# Tratamento de JSON retornado do PHP

Tags: java, android, json

Gostaria de saber como faço para manipular os dados do `JSON` abaixo. Se a estrutura está correta, e se não, como mudo a estrutura do mesmo?

```
{
    "postagens":[
    {
        "URLIMG":"1.jpg",
        "NOME":"Jhonatan",
        "SOBRENOME":"Pereira",
        "ID":"2",
        "IDUSER":"1",
        "POST":"Mais uma postagem de teste"
    },
    {
        "URLIMG":"1.jpg",
        "NOME":"Jhonatan",
        "SOBRENOME":"Pereira",
        "ID":"1",
        "IDUSER":"1",
        "POST":"Fim!"
    }],
    "ups":[
        ["1"],
        ["2"]
    ]
}
```

O `PHP` que gera esse `JSON` é:

```
$id = $_POST['id']; // id do usuário, igual a 1 para teste.
try {
    //conexao com o BD ocultada aqui (variavel $db)
    $contractQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT du.URLIMG, du.NOME, du.SOBRENOME, f.ID, f.IDUSER, f.CURTIDAS, f.NAOCURTIDAS, f.HORA, f.DIA, f.MES, f.ANO, f.POST FROM appfeed f, appdadosuser du WHERE f.IDUSER = du.ID ORDER BY f.ID DESC LIMIT 0 , 30");

    $typesQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT IDPOST FROM appcurtidas WHERE `iduser` = 1 LIMIT 0 , 30");

    $contractQuery->execute(array($id));
    $typesQuery->execute(array($id));

    $result = array();
    $result['postagens'] = $contractQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $result['ups'] = $typesQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    echo json_encode($result); //return json
} catch (PDOException $exc) {

}
```

Sei que devo usar `JSONArray` e `JSONObject`, e que `Object` é `{}` e `Array` é `[]`, só não estou conseguindo pensar na utilização devido ao trecho que difere do restante do `JSON`:

```
"ups":[
        ["1"],
        ["2"]
    ]
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesses links: http://json.org/json-pt.html e http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

Comment: E segundo https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/, esse JSON é válido.

Comment: Verei e retorno o resultado amanhã ^^ valeu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui solucionar de uma maneira mais simples, utilizando a biblioteca org.json.*

**JSON retornado do PHP:**

```js
{"postagens":
    [{"URLIMG":"1.jpg",
      "NOME":"Jhonatan",
      "SOBRENOME":"Pereira",
      "ID":"2",
      "IDUSER":"1",
      "CURTIDAS":"0",
      "NAOCURTIDAS":"0",
      "HORA":"22:25",
      "DIA":"26",
      "MES":"9",
      "ANO":"2015",
      "POST":"Mais uma postagem de teste"},

     {
          "URLIMG":"1.jpg",
          "NOME":"Jhonatan",
          "SOBRENOME":"Pereira",
          "ID":"1",
          "IDUSER":"1",
          "CURTIDAS":"0",
          "NAOCURTIDAS":"0",
          "HORA":"22:00",
          "DIA":"26",
          "MES":"9",
          "ANO":"2015",
          "POST":"Fim da lista de postagens."
     }],
"ups":[
    {"IDPOST":"1"},
    {"IDPOST":"2"}
]
```

}

**Código Java:**

```
//variável JSON é o JSON retornado da Web
String[] postsCurtidos; //Receberá os valores de "ups" do JSON
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(JSON);

        //Separa os dois arrays do JSON, "postagens" e "ups"
        JSONArray postagens = json.getJSONArray("postagens");
        JSONArray ups = json.getJSONArray("ups");

        //define o tamanho do vetor usado para armazenar os UPs IDs
        postsCurtidos = new String[ups.length()];

        //captura os dados de "ups"
        for (int indexUp = 0; indexUp < ups.length(); indexUp++){
            JSONObject linesUp = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(ups.getString(indexUp)).nextValue();
            //preenche o vetor com os ids dos ups do JSON
            postsCurtidos[indexUp] = linesUp.getString("IDPOST");
        }

        //agora captura os dados de "postagens"
        for(int indexPost = 0; indexPost < json.length(); indexPost++) {
            JSONObject lines = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(postagens.getString(indexPost)).nextValue();

            //lines.getString(nome da chave do JSON);
            String nomeCompleto = lines.getString("NOME")+" "+lines.getString("SOBRENOME");
            usuario.setText(nomeCompleto);

            text.setText(lines.getString("POST"));
            int anoBD = Integer.valueOf(lines.getString("ANO"));
            int mesDB = Integer.parseInt(lines.getString("MES"));
            int diaDB = Integer.parseInt(lines.getString("DIA"));

         }
      }//fim try, seguido de catch
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode seguir os seguintes passos
1- criar classes pojo
2- adicionar a lib retrofit ao seu projeto
3- realizar requisições utilizando o conceito rest(por isso o passo 2)

**1 criar classes pojo**

A classe "pojo" serve para modelar no java a estrutura do seu json, basicamente ela representa no lado android os dados que serão recebidos para o json. Essa classe é utilizada pelo retrofit para converter o json recebido para a estrutura da classe passada(pojo). Você pode gerar essas classes(pojo) utilizando o seguinte site: http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/ basta você copiar um json válido e ele te retornará as classes pojo. Para o seu caso temos

**Postagens.java**

```
public class Postagens{

private String POST;

private String URLIMG;

private String ID;

private String SOBRENOME;

private String IDUSER;

private String NOME;

public String getPOST ()
{
    return POST;
}

public void setPOST (String POST)
{
    this.POST = POST;
}

public String getURLIMG ()
{
    return URLIMG;
}

public void setURLIMG (String URLIMG)
{
    this.URLIMG = URLIMG;
}

public String getID ()
{
    return ID;
}

public void setID (String ID)
{
    this.ID = ID;
}

public String getSOBRENOME ()
{
    return SOBRENOME;
}

public void setSOBRENOME (String SOBRENOME)
{
    this.SOBRENOME = SOBRENOME;
}

public String getIDUSER ()
{
    return IDUSER;
}

public void setIDUSER (String IDUSER)
{
    this.IDUSER = IDUSER;
}

public String getNOME ()
{
    return NOME;
}

public void setNOME (String NOME)
{
    this.NOME = NOME;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [POST = "+POST+", URLIMG = "+URLIMG+", ID = "+ID+", SOBRENOME = "+SOBRENOME+", IDUSER = "+IDUSER+", NOME = "+NOME+"]";
}}
```

**MyPojo.java**

```
public class MyPojo{

private Postagens[] postagens;

private String[][] ups;

public Postagens[] getPostagens ()
{
    return postagens;
}

public void setPostagens (Postagens[] postagens)
{
    this.postagens = postagens;
}

public String[][] getUps ()
{
    return ups;
}

public void setUps (String[][] ups)
{
    this.ups = ups;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [postagens = "+postagens+", ups = "+ups+"]";
}}
```

**2 adicionar retrofit**

Essa lib é responsável por fazer requisições e "abstrair" toda codificação necessária, você pode encontra-la aqui: http://square.github.io/retrofit/
conceito rest : https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST

**3 Requisições usando rest**

Para este passo é necessário que você tenha lido e entendido o passo 2.
Segue abaixo um exemplo de como usar o retrofit.

**Interface Retrofit**

```
public interface RetrofitService {
@GET("/postagens/{user_id})
Call<MyPojo> getPostagens(@Path ("user_id")String user);}
```

Nesta interface será adicionada todas as suas requisições em será feito o uso do retrofit. O próximo passo é onde será feito a requisição para o seu problema para isso é necessário adicionar a base da url do servidor ao qual será feito a requisição, é importante que seja retirado a"/" do fim da url. Segue o código:

```
public class Requisicao {
private static Retrofit retrofit;
private static RetrofitService service;
public static MyPojo getPostagens(String user_id){
```

//adicionando base url

```
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("URL_BASE")//exemplo: www.facebook.com

                    //GsonConverterFactory é utilizada para transformar  o //json na classe MyPojo

            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    service = retrofit.create(AvososService.class);//utilizando metodo definido na interface
```

//com essa chamada temos a seguinte url www.baseurl.com/postagens/user_id

```
    Call<MyPojo> postagens= service.getPostagens(user_id);
```

//verificando o retorno

```
    postagens.enqueue(new Callback<MyPojo>() {
        MyPojo mPojo;
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<MyPojo> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            if (response.message().equals("OK"))//retorno da requisicao ok 
            {
                mPojo = response.getBody();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    return mPojo;
}}
```

É necessário adicionar no build.gradle do projeto a seguinte dependência que fará o importa da classe *GsonConverterFactory*

> compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'

Feito isso para a realizar a requisição basta fazer:

```
Requisicao.getPostagens(user_id);
```